# How do you "take back" a close vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have made mistakes in my close vote and have at times wanted to reverse my vote at a later time.

I have not found a way to do this?  Is this currently possible?

If not, could there be logic added to make this possible?

Answer (score 6):

[You can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes). You just wait patiently and it will expire in a few days.

Comment: Close votes only begin expiring once the question has received 100 views.

Comment: Or, if sufficient people (including one moderator) cast Leave Open votes in the /review/close queue then a question is removed from the queue and votes start aging away immediately.

Answer (score 1):

A couple other options:

- If the question gets closed, you can then cast a re-open vote.
- If you think a question was closed in error (maybe your vote led to a pile-on of close votes...) you can flag it for a moderator to look at.

Comment: As moderators, there really isn't much we can do. We can't invalidate close votes except by closing and reopening a question and that invalidates all votes not just the vote of the person who changed their mind. Even with only one vote, we wouldn't know (can't check) if the person requesting the vote be invalidated really had cast the vote or just disagreed with it and was being devious.